# Apache Beam Python SDK on Flink Runner to use Snowflake IO

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-flink, apache-beam

I have an existing Flink cluster in k8s.
I am using Flink's session mode.

I want to set up a periodic ETL job from Snowflake using Apache Beam. Thus, I have tried to use `from apache_beam.io.snowflake import ReadFromSnowflake`. I am aware that an expansion service is required, but here is where I am struggling.

I have set up Python worker, and a Bean flink runner job server (version 2.43.0) as a sidecar in k8s pod.

I have passed these pipeline options.

```
[
      "--runner=FlinkRunner",
      "--flink_version=1.15",
      "--flink_master=http://{host}:8081",
      "--environment_type=EXTERNAL",
      "--environment_config=localhost:50000",
      "--flink_submit_uber_jar",
]
```

However, I am seeing the following logs.

```
2022/12/03 11:28:26 Failed to retrieve staged files: failed to retrieve /tmp/1-1/staged in 3 attempts: failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/1-1/staged/beam-sdks-java-io-snowflake-expansion-service-2.43.0-4Bf-1AqvnTnIQ0PSXTz9S5MQ4RrIvMC3eNLcBf99voU.jar
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Canceled desc = Server sendMessage() failed with Error; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/1-1/staged/beam-sdks-java-io-snowflake-expansion-service-2.43.0-4Bf-1AqvnTnIQ0PSXTz9S5MQ4RrIvMC3eNLcBf99voU.jar
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Canceled desc = Server sendMessage() failed with Error; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/1-1/staged/beam-sdks-java-io-snowflake-expansion-service-2.43.0-4Bf-1AqvnTnIQ0PSXTz9S5MQ4RrIvMC3eNLcBf99voU.jar
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected EOF; failed to retrieve chunk for /tmp/1-1/staged/beam-sdks-java-io-snowflake-expansion-service-2.43.0-4Bf-1AqvnTnIQ0PSXTz9S5MQ4RrIvMC3eNLcBf99voU.jar
    caused by:
rpc error: code = Internal desc = unexpected EOF
```

I have started the expansion service using `beam-sdks-java-io-snowflake-expansion-service-2.43.0.jar`. I am unsure why the service isn't retrieved.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using [FlinkRunner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/), and it means that it will use non-portable Flink.

I have checked with a committer that works on portability ([@chamikara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4696015/chamikara)) and he suggested using the [PortableRunner](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/runners/portability/PortableRunner.html) if you need portability.

Comment: This means I need a separate Job Server, correct? Do I need to spin up a separate expansion service and a job server for every portable app? In k8s, could I have one pod that runs job server, another pod that runs expansion service so that these two pods can be shared across multiple Beam pods?

Comment: I believe this should help to clarify things a bit: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java-multi-language-pipelines/#advanced-start-an-expansion-service. If not, let me know and I can try to reach someone with more information on this.